# Compare two files any format c#

Tags: c#

I am working on a application that takes in either two folders for files and compares them against one another and outputs any differences. I have the portion that takes the contents of two files and then outputs any differences in file names. Now I want to take the files that are the same in both folders and compare them to see if they are different. My first guess is to check them so see if the binary using a byte reader I have been trying this and cannot get something to work. I found one solution below but cannot get it to work. Does someone have a starting point or some sample code to get me started. I want to try to make it universal to any file type. i.e. text, docx, exe, pdf, mp3, mp4, xlsx...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Read the file into <bits>
        try
        {
            var fs = new FileStream(Console.ReadLine(), FileMode.Open);
            var len = (int)fs.Length;
            var bits = new byte[len];
            fs.Read(bits, 0, len);
            // Dump 16 bytes per line
            for (int ix = 0; ix < len; ix += 16)
            {
                var cnt = Math.Min(16, len - ix);
                var line = new byte[cnt];
                Array.Copy(bits, ix, line, 0, cnt);
                // Write address + hex + ascii
                Console.Write("{0:X6}  ", ix);
                Console.Write(BitConverter.ToString(line));
                Console.Write("  ");
                // Convert non-ascii characters to .
                for (int jx = 0; jx < cnt; ++jx)
                    if (line[jx] < 0x20 || line[jx] > 0x7f) line[jx] = (byte)'.';
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(line));
                Console.Read();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

Comment: " I found one solution below but cannot get it to work." - is not a question.

Comment: I was trying to find a easier and better way of doing it and the MD5 hash was a very good and helpful alternative. byte-by-byte is more accurate in theory but more difficult to implement and for novice developers more difficult

Comment: @user3753693 Using hash for comparing two files is slower and less reliable than direct compassion, but If you still want to do that consider using algorithms with less collision rate that md5, for example sha512, but it's calculation even slower that md5 and still not that repayable as direct comparison.

Comment: Thank you I did see that when i used your solution it took around 7 miliseconds for a 3mb file. using hash it took around 48 miliseconds. using hash starting off is easier to implement and worked everytime. I am still looking into how to better use the byte-to-byte methods to work on all files. Sometimes i need to compare mulit gb files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A different aproach and much simpler in my opinion would be using MD5 Hash:

```
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\Test.txt";
        string filePath2 = @"C:\Users\Gabriel\Desktop\Test2.txt";
        string hash;
        string hash2;

        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                hash = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath2))
            {
                hash2 = BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
            }
        }
        if (hash == hash2)
        {
            // Both files are the same, so you can do your stuff here
        }
```

Be aware that MD5 Hash uses the contents of the file to define if they are the same, but it doesn't consider its name. So if you create 2 identical text files with different names it will be considered the same. If you need it to check the names too you could try changing the last if statement to something like that:

```
        if (hash == hash2)
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(filePath2);
            if (file.Name == file2.Name)
            {
                // Both files are the same, so you can do your stuff here
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the way it should be done IMO. In theory you could get false positives, but the chances are very slim unless you are working huge volumes of files.

Comment: To my opinion hash comparison should be used if you have more that two similar files. If there are only two files computing hash is slower than direct comparison and less repayable. Because any hash algorithm still read whole file and also make some calculation base on it's data. Could you please explain why do you chose hash here?

Answer (score 0):

May be this class will be useful for comparing files:

```
public class FileComparator
{
    private const int _bufferCapacity = 0x400000; //4Mb

    public static bool AreEquals(string first, string second)
    {
        return AreEquals(File.OpenRead(first), File.OpenRead(second));
    }

    public static bool AreEquals(FileStream first, FileStream second)
    {
        using (var firstStream = new BufferedStream(first))
        using (var secondStream = new BufferedStream(second))
        {
            if (first.Length != second.Length)
                return false;

            var firstBuffer = new byte[_bufferCapacity];
            var secondBuffer = new byte[_bufferCapacity];

            int bytesReadFirst;
            int bytesReadSecond;
            do
            {
                bytesReadFirst = firstStream.Read(firstBuffer, 0, firstBuffer.Length);
                bytesReadSecond = secondStream.Read(secondBuffer, 0, secondBuffer.Length);
                if (bytesReadFirst != bytesReadSecond || !CompareByteArrays(firstBuffer, secondBuffer))
                    return false;
            } while (bytesReadFirst > 0 && bytesReadSecond > 0);
            return true;
        }
    }


    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    static extern int memcmp(byte[] b1, byte[] b2, long count);

    private static bool CompareByteArrays(byte[] first, byte[] second)
    {
        return first.Length == second.Length && memcmp(first, second, first.Length) == 0;
    }
}
```

You can use it by passing file names as arguments or just streams:

```
var result = FileComparator.AreEquals(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine());
```

If don't want to use 'DllImport' in your code you could replece it with call of `SequanceEquals` but it will be much slower.

Comment: So if the files are larger than 4MB but of different sizes you'll still do an unnecessary byte-by-byte comparison on all but the last buffer, when you could have returned false early.

Comment: @JimGarrison thank's I've mist that, originally it was designed to work  with any kind of streams, and I forgot that we could compare file size before content comparison. I've made fixes to solution.

Comment: @AndreyTretyak I was able to get this to work finally. Can I make this so it will work on any size file. I tried playing with the buffer and got a buffer overflow arithmetic error.

Comment: @user3753693 sorry I've missed `!` before `CompareByteArrays`. About working with any size of file: `_bufferCapacity` is only define which part of file will be read for one iteration of the loop, but solution can work with any file sizes. I've tested it with 200 Mb files and any bigger should not be a problem.

Comment: @user3753693 I've fixed wrong condition, please try it now